# Python: How do I divide each item in a string by a number?

Tags: python

Can anyone please kindly explain why I get this error? Thanks!

```
counts = '2,4,6,8,10'
divisor = counts.split(',')
quotient = [20/number for number in divisor]
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
> ```

Edit:
Thank you for the suggestions. I've amended my code:

```
counts = '2,4,6,8,10'
divisor = counts.split(',')
quotient = [20/number for number in divisor]
```

How do I print the result of the division like this
20 / 2 = 10
for each of the divisors?

Answer (score 2):

So you just need to transform your string to int:

```
counts = '2,4,6,8,10'
divisor = counts.split(',')
quotient = [20/int(number) for number in divisor]
print(quotient)
```

You can read more on this transformation in: [https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-string-to-int/#:~:text=To%20convert%20a%20string%20to,as%20an%20int%20%2C%20or%20integer](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-string-to-int/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20a%20string%20to,as%20an%20int%20%2C%20or%20integer).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that a number can't be divided by a string. Let's take a look closely:

`counts` is a string, i.e, it is an instance of the `str` class. When you apply the method `split` over `counts`, you're creating a list of string, it means that every position of this list contains an instance of the `str` class, this list correspond to `['2', '4', '6', '8', '10']` and you store it in `divisor`. There is no problem until here.

Finally, in the line:

```
quotient = [20/number for number in divisor]
```

You're trying to divide `20`, an instance of the `int` class, by the strings stored in `divisor`, which has no sense because they're all instances of `str`. That's why you get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

In simple words, isn't allowed to use the operator `/` between `int` and `str`.

As the others answers say, all you have to do is to cast the elements in `divisor` to integers, then the correct way is the following:

```
counts = '2,4,6,8,10'
divisor = counts.split(',')
quotient = [20/int(number) for number in divisor]
print(quotient)
```

Notice that the conversion is done by `int(number)`, so for example, in the first iteration you'll have `int('2')` which returns `2` (without the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to be as follows:

```
counts = '2,4,6,8,10'
divisor = counts.split(',')
quotient = [20/int(number) for number in divisor]
print(quotient)
```

You are trying to divide int by string which is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

divisor List holding values of type str. In line 3 you are trying to devide int by str.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a list (or any other iters) of string numbers, to integer numbers, just like this:

```
counts = '2,4,6,8,10'
divisor = counts.split(',')

# key line below
divisor = map(lambda n: int(n), divisor)

quotient = [20/number for number in divisor]
print(quotient)
```

Answer (score -1):

Cast the string items to `int`:

```
counts = '2,4,6,8,10'
divisor = counts.split(',')
quotient = [20/int(number) for number in divisor]
print(quotient)
```

Short version:

```
print([20/int(x) for x in counts.split(',')])
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes on the three answers, which are correct? We have just 1 minute difference from the first answer, which is quite fast.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have to do anything with that